# limit distribution of possion distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume Xn is possion with mean $\lambda_n$ and suppose that $\lambda_n\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Then how to show Xn is AN$(\lambda_n,\lambda_n)$. I've tried to use characteristic function , but failed.

Comment: Can you show your computation of characteristic function?

Comment: While we are at it, what is the meaning of "$X_n$ is AN$(\lambda_n,\lambda_n)$"?

Comment: And are you [user rand](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/386467)? If yes, I suggest to begin to answer to the comments made on your questions before asking other questions.